# 2 Wifi cards with 2 different jobs

Tags: raspbian, wireless, wireless-adapter

I have an RPI 3B+ and a wifi dongle that can support monitor mode. I look for ways on google on how to use the internal card to connect to ssh and the wifi dongle to use it for monitor mode using the software airmon-ng and didn't have any luck.

Could you please help me in the most simple way?!

P.S. I have 1% knowledge of programming!

Answer (score 1):

**Prevent dhcpcd from configuring an interface** in [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) shows how to stop `dhcpcd` configuring an interface.

NOTE Predictable Network Interface Names is recommended if multiple WiFi interfaces are in use.